# Is the SharePoint Client Context compatible with Mono?

Tags: 2013, synchronisation, sync, client

I have a SharePoint 2013 custom application built, and I want to start building an iOS application that can sync List data to and from the SP site.  I know that I could use the SOAP/REST endpoints, but I am looking for "the better way".  One idea I had is to use the client context within Mono, but I can't tell if it is supported.

From [Mono's website:](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)

> The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is:
>   Everything in .NET 4.5 except WPF, WWF, and with limited WCF and limited ASP.NET 4.5 async stack.

It sounds like Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext would be supported then.

Has anyone here successfully used the Client Context library within Mono?

Comment: Beside compatibility with Mono (that should be OK based on the statement from them), another important aspect is how you plan the authentication from the iOS client application. Have you any plan for that? What kind of authentication does your SharePoint application supports? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - it will probably be the bigger issue.  Right now my site only supports Windows Auth :(

Comment: Actually, I think using the ClientContext would solve the auth issue for me since it lets you supply credentials programmatically.  I'll post an answer here after some experimentation (might take me awhile to get to it).

Comment: The license is scary - which seems to prohibit "distribute Distributable Code to run on a platform other than the Windows platform"